# How to correctly determine if a Pandas dataframe has replaced values in a column based on a string in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have a really large Pandas dataframe in Python with three important columns; 'file', 'comment', and 'number'. It is a list of many different files with assigned id-numbers, but some of these files replaces old files and should have the same id-numbers instead of separate ones. An example is:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data = None, columns = ['file','comment','number'])
df_test.file = ['file_1', 'file_1_v2', 'file_2', 'file_2_v2', 'file_3', 'file_3_v2']
df_test.comment = ['none', 'Replacing: file_1', 'none', 'Replacing: file_2', 'none', 'Replacing: file_3']
df_test.number = ['12', '12', '15', '16', '18', '18']
```

What I want is to check if the 'number' column shows the same id-number for the original file and the file which has a comment that starts with 'Replacing: ' that compares the number with the file shown at the end of the comment. In this example, I would want something like a list or a new column in the dataframe which reads; 'True', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'True', 'True'; since the second and last files have been assigned the same id-number as the file they are replacing, but the fourth file has not. I can't really figure out how to check it and any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If always `none` are before replacing files, is possible replace it to missing values and back filling missing values for helper `Series` of groups, last test if unique `number` per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
s = df_test['comment'].mask(df_test['comment'].eq('none')).bfill()
df_test['test'] = df_test.groupby(s)['number'].transform('nunique').eq(1)
print (df_test)

        file            comment number   test
0     file_1               none     12   True
1  file_1_v2  Replacing: file_1     12   True
2     file_2               none     15  False
3  file_2_v2  Replacing: file_2     16  False
4     file_3               none     18   True
5  file_3_v2  Replacing: file_3     18   True
```

Another idea for groups is extract filenames after last space in [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with replace non matched values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and test uniquness per groups like previous solution:

```
s = df_test['comment'].str.extract(r'\s(.*)$', expand=False).fillna(df_test['file'])
df_test['test'] = df_test.groupby(s)['number'].transform('nunique').eq(1)
print (df_test)
        file            comment number   test
0     file_1               none     12   True
1  file_1_v2  Replacing: file_1     12   True
2     file_2               none     15  False
3  file_2_v2  Replacing: file_2     16  False
4     file_3               none     18   True
5  file_3_v2  Replacing: file_3     18   True
```